# Export or Copy TFS 2010 Team Project and Collection Groups to different Collection and Project

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am trying to determine if there is a way to either export/import Collection and Project Groups or copy them to a different Collection and/or Project.  I know for our test setup I can copy the complete collection over, but it would be helpful in our case just to get the groups.